# Как сделать неограниченное количество яндекс карт на одной странице?

Tags: html, yandex-maps-api

Стоит задача заверстать большое количество карт на одной странице, какое именно - неизвестно, но их может быть очень много.
Инициализировать ее нужно по клику, так как карты находятся в табах, ну и соотвественно при переходе на другой таб, скрывать предыдущую и показывать новую, то есть инициализировать новую карту, а старую убирать.

Насколько я понял, яндекс API позволяет вызывать ее тольео по id, Значит мне надо как-то параметром передавать этот id. В идеале контейнеру через data-attr надо передавать координаты еще.

До чего дошел сам на данный момент:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.carousel-flights-item').click(function(){
        showMap();
        initYaMap ();
        return false;
    });

});

function initYaMap () {

    ymaps.ready(init);
    var myMap;

    function init(){
        myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map", {
            center: [53.35, 83.73],
            zoom: 4
        });
    }

}


<div class="tracking-map">
    <div class="tracking-map__yandex-map" id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
 </div>
```

P.S. Если нужна доп информаци или рабочий код, пишите выложу на codepen.

Comment: смысл спрашивать то, на что знаешь ответ?

Comment: @Jean-Claude видимо, чтобы другие кто будет искать, сразу и нашли ответ. Это как задал вопрос, и ответил на него через некоторое время :)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев есть проблема на данный момент, при переключении табов предыдущая карта не исчезает(